# Error 3070003: Serialization Error Processing WASM while set contract eosio.system

Tags: nodeos, cleos, eosio-code, eosio.token, eosio.cdt

set contract: cleos set contract eosio ./eosio.system -p eosio@active
I get : Error 3070003: Serialization Error Processing WASM

Publishing contract...
Error 3070003: Serialization Error Processing WASM
Error Details:
env.set_proposed_producers_ex unresolveable
pending console output:

Comment: Please share some information about your system and the versions you are using,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.